# Cone - Determine $s$ as function $s(V)$

Tags: functions

Determine the length of the slant height $s$ as a function of the volume $V$, where $s=d$.

$s(V)=\ ...$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let's start with the setup...do you know the formula for the volume of a cone?

Comment: yes ... $V=1/3*r^2*\pi*h$

Comment: Next, notice that if the slant height $s$ is always equal to the diameter $d$, then we can say that $h = \frac{\sqrt{3}s}{2}$. Can you see why this is the case? (Hint: think of viewing the cone as if it was on a piece of paper where it now looks like a triangle with sides $s,s,d$ but recall $s=d$ )

Comment: yes, since all sides are $s$ long, the pythagorean theorem says that $h=\sqrt{3}\ \frac{s}{2}$

Comment: All that's left is the algebra. Substitute into the volume equation your new value for $h$ in terms of $s$ and don't forget to substitute $r= s/2$ either. From here solve for $s$. See if you can take it from here.

Comment: $V=\frac{1}{3}\ (\frac{s}{2})^2\ \pi\ \frac{\sqrt{3}s}{2}$ should then solve to $s=2*\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi}\ V}$ but i get $s=2*\sqrt[3]{\frac{V}{\sqrt{3}\ \pi}}$. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You most likely forgot a $3$ that remains when you take out the $2^3$ from $24$

Comment: wow, how stupid from me, thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     ^
    /|\
 s / | \ s
  /  |h \
 /   |   \ 
-----------
  s/2
```

$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
s&=d=2r\\\
s^2&=h^2+(\frac{s}{2})^2 \Rightarrow h=\sqrt{s^2-(\frac{s}{2})^2}=\sqrt{3}\  \frac{s}{2}\\\
V&=\frac{1}{3}\ r^2 \ \pi \ h\\\
V&=\frac{1}{3}\ (\frac{s}{2})^2\ \pi \ \frac{\sqrt{3}\ s}{2}\\\
V&=\frac{s^3}{24}\ \pi \ \sqrt{3}\ \ \ \vert *24 \ \ \ \vert : (\pi\ \sqrt{3}) \ \ \ \vert *\sqrt[3]{}\\\
s&=\sqrt[3]{\frac{2^3\ 3\ V}{\sqrt{3}\ \pi}\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}}\\\
s&=2\ \sqrt[3]{\frac{\cancel{3}\ \sqrt{3}\ V}{\cancel{3}\ \pi}}\\\
s&=2\ \sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi}\ V}\ \Longrightarrow s(V)=2\ \sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi}\ V}\\\
\end{align}
$